# Alternatives to using Java Servlets for reading and writing to an Ethernet Port

Tags: java, php, servlets

I'm currently reading some data over a Ethernet port using GET and POST methods and I have made use of Java Servlets.

I was wondering if there is some alternative to Servlets, for example can I achieve the same using purely PHP or something else?

My goal is to eliminate the use of Servlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TCP/IP sockets directly. Here's a tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Note that you can't write Ethernet frames directly in pure Java since there's no support for that - you're limited to the IP protocols TCP and UDP.